# How to calculate comparison highest value to lowest value in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Here's my dataset

```
a.age              15-20       21-34       35-50         <15         >50
829             0.973257    0.960501    0.953244    0.966997    0.957140
1030            0.943649    0.921949    0.890820    0.948845    0.902489
```

Here's my expected output
Comparison is the highest comparing to the lowest age group

```
a.age              15-20       21-34       35-50         <15         >50           comparison
829             0.973257    0.960501    0.953244    0.966997    0.957140    1.020994624671123        
1030            0.943649    0.921949    0.890820    0.948845    0.902489   1.0593037875216094
```

**Note:**

`a.age` is index column

Comparison had `1.020994624671123` value is come from `0.973257/0.953244`, `15-20` compare to `35-50`

Comparison had `1.020994624671123` value is come from `0.943649/0.890820`, `<15` compare to `35-50`

Comment: how its calculated?

Comment: @Naveed Already Edited

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aggregate age like columns with `min` and `max` along `axis=1`, then divide `max` / `min` value to calculate ratio:

```
s = df.agg(['min', 'max'], axis=1)
df['comparision'] = s['max'] / s['min']
```

---

```
   a.age     15-20     21-34     35-50       <15       >50  comparision
0    829  0.973257  0.960501  0.953244  0.966997  0.957140     1.020995
1   1030  0.943649  0.921949  0.890820  0.948845  0.902489     1.065137
```

Note: I am assuming that column `a.age` is already set as the index of dataframe.